# How do I perform and interpret an Ancova/Poisson Regression, with multiple covariates and possible interactions?

Tags: r, regression, multivariate-analysis, interaction, ancova

I am researching how recovery time of trees after tropical wildfires differs between South America, Africa and Australia, using R. For this, I am using a Poisson regression. 
First I checked if there is any difference:

> glm(RecTime ~ Continent, family = poisson(link = "log"))

And there is indeed a significant difference in mean recovery time between the continents.

However, now I want to check if this difference can be explained by one (or more) of the five covariates I have information on (let's call them A, B, C, D and E), or that the results indicate that we have to look for other factors creating this difference. It is very probable that A,B,C,D&E interact with each other and with the factor continent. So i believe that running the model without interaction is not an option. Is it possible to run the model accounting for interactions between allindependent variables? Like:

> glm(RecTime ~continent * A * B * C * D, family = poisson(link = "log"))

Or should I deal with this another way? Should I first check if all these variables interact with each other individually?

If this is indeed the right way to study this, how do I interpret the results? When I perform the model as described above, I obtain an anova table where continent is significant and all the interaction terms that include continent are significant too. All the other terms are not significant.

Thank you very much for your time.

Comment: Before you establish the best way to test interactions, are you sure a Poisson model is applicable? Typically Poisson is used not when time will vary but when you have measured counts of events:  x events occurred here in a given timeframe, z events occurred there, etc.  And then for Poisson to work best, your dependent variable should meet the assumption that the mean =~ the variance.

Comment: @rolando2 thank you for your reaction. That's a fair point you're making. My data looks as follows: 
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/thkgw.png

This project is for a research project for my master. After checking assumptions and transforming my data a lot, without succes, my supervisor and I decided that I had to find the best fit and continue, eventhough that fit did not really meet the assumptions. Of course this is a big problem... but in my timeframe and with our knowledge, we didn't find another solution.

Comment: @rolando2 
However, I just checked why poisson fitted better and I didn't find any difference with a regular ancova. The residual plots of both, look like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/dEq1k.jpg
I know this isn't my original question and it is very messy of me that I use this data. But if you have an idea on how I can still use these data (transformations/ different tests), any help is welcome :)

Comment: If only a single approach could be most convenient, familiar, rigorous, informative, acceptable...you may need more than one.